# Rails accessing information from many-to-many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking to share lessons between users in a rails application. User A has created some lessons and would like to share it with user B & C. User A creates a lesson, adds users B & C to the lesson and they now can see the lesson. My problem is how I can get the shared lessons to appear in users B & C shared page? Each lesson belongs to a notebook.

**notebook.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :lessons, :dependent => :destroy
```

**lesson.rb**

```
belongs_to :notebook
has_many :shareships
has_many :users, through: :shareships, dependent: :destroy
attr_reader :user_tokens
accepts_nested_attributes_for :shareships, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:user_ids].blank? }
scope :shared, lambda { where('shared_ids = ?')
```

**user.rb**

```
has_many :notebooks, dependent: :destroy
```

**shareship.rb**

```
belongs_to :lesson
belongs_to :user
```

**lessons_controller.rb**

```
class LessonsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authorize, :find_notebook
  load_and_authorize_resource :through => :notebook, :except => [:public]
  respond_to :html, :js, :json 


  def create
    @lesson = @notebook.lessons.build(params[:lesson])
    @lesson.user_id = current_user.id
    flash[:notice] = 'lesson Added!.' if @lesson.save
    respond_with(@lesson, :location => notebook_lessons_path)
  end


    def shared
      @user = current_user
      @shared = @notebook.lessons
    end
end
```

I have setup the many to many association between users and lessons so users can add other users to a lesson but I am trying to figure out how to list the lessons for the shared users. Any ideas how I can get this to work? I am having trouble setting it up and my controller and view.

Comment: Is notebook model really necessary? Don't you miss has_many :lesson for user model?

Comment: @oldergod yes because each time a user creates a notebook they will have a new set of lessons and can go back to old ones. I also captured the userid in the lesson controller so I can track notes by users also.

Comment: Don't you miss has_many :lesson for user model? So you could just call user.lessons and you will get what you are looking for, am I wrong ?

Comment: @oldergod yes I would do it like so if I were planning on users erasing and starting over but I would like them to have control over each and every notebook. So the above is easier but I would like to access a lesson based on if a lesson is shared with me and other users through a specific notebook if that makes sense.

Comment: could you write an example of what you want to do ?

Comment: @oldergod I would like to show a lesson that a user has shared with another user. User A has 3 notebooks but shares a lesson from notebook 1. When users B gets added to the lesson he will be able to see it regardless of what notebook it is in through a url like so test.com/notebooks/shared. Any idea how I can accomplished this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this

**notebook.rb**

```
has_many :lessons
belongs_to :user
```

**lesson.rb**

```
belongs_to :notebook
has_many :shareships
has_many :users, through: :shareships, dependent: :destroy # shared users of this lesson, not the owner
```

**user.rb**

```
has_many :notebook # the user will go through the notebook to get the lesson he owns
has_many :shareships
has_many :lessons, through: :shareships, dependent: :destroy # this would be only the shared lessons he has access to
```

**shareship.rb**

```
belongs_to :lesson
belongs_to :user
```

A user would have access the lesson he owns via

```
/:user_id/notebooks/:notebook_id/lesson/:lesson_id 
# lessons = user.notebooks[:notebook_id].lessons
```

and he would have access to the lessons shared with him via

```
/:user_id/shared_lessons/:lesson_id
# shared_lessons = user.lessons
```

The user does not have straight access to the lessons he owns, he needs to go through his notebooks. But he has straight access to the shared lessons.

what do you think ?